# Create filter view in google analytics to only show impression if it occurs on select domain, rather than on test / dev VPS or other

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

**SHORT QUESTION:**

Is there a way I can create a filter view in Google Analytics so that a view / impression / user etc only shows up in the report if it took place on mydomain.com, but not if it took place on my test VPSs IP (or any other domain or IP for that matter)?

**LONG QUESTION:**

I've got a production site running on mydomain.com and I've also got a dev server running on a ip url (no domain name).

When I test the dev site before pushing to production, it sometimes show up in my Google analytics. I've got the Google Analytics opt out plugin installed on all my desktop browsers, but I can't do this on my mobile devices. I've also got our office IP blocked in Google Analytics, but sometimes I test from home (where I've got a dynamic IP). I also use Browserstack.com which basically allows you to connect to a hosted virtual machine over a teamviewer type setup so you can test you site on any browser OS combo you want, and Browserstack uses a range of IPs for their virtual machines.

Becuase of this there doesn't seem to be one bullet proof client side method to stop myself testing the site showing up in the production site's Google Analytics reports.

Is there a way I can create a filter the view in Google Analytics so that a view / impression / user etc only shows up in the report if it took place on mydomain.com, but not if it took place on my test VPSs IP (or any other domain or IP for that matter)?

Answer (score 1):

Found a tutorial on how to do this here : http://bradsknutson.com/blog/google-analytics-quick-tip-prevent-tracking-code-theft/

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered answers, because links tend to go stale (as this one has). Please edit your answer to be complete without the link.